# Representing points as polygons from Feflow data in QGIS

Tags: qgis, point, polygon-creation, vector-layer, geometry-conversion

I have several Feflow files that are displayed as points in QGIS. I would like to display points that have the same value scale as a polygon (F Value in the attribute table). Is this possible?

Is there no function like point to polygon? (Like select all points with the same value and form a polygon)
I have already tried

- Theisen Polygon (this seems quite wrong to me)
- Convert point to polygon

It is also possible to save the Feflow file as a shapefile with polygons. Then the polygon contains single triangles. Here is the problem at the end, the file size.

Could I possibly convert the individual triangles to a surface?

Shapefile with points
[image: Shapefile with points]

Attribute Table of the point shapefile
[image: Attribute Table of the point shapefile]

Shapefile with the triangles
[image: Shapefile with the triangles]

Comment: You can use concave hull (it will not work in some cases) : https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#qgisknearestconcavehull

Comment: I believe you are looking for the dissolve tool with the triangles it will work fine with F as field to group

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dissolve will work using your polygon shapefile with the triangles if you select "F" in the dissolve field

input
[image]
output
[image]

Comment: Also if you expect distinct polygons with the same F value they will be part of the same MultiPolygon. If you would prefer them to be separate polygons you can use "Multipart to singleparts" processing tool to do so